# click() method is not working

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I have a link which is having the `href` attribute as `javascript:void(0)`, but it is having the `onclick` function. In the `onclick` function `dev` is use to log the number of hits to be database through ajax calls and based on the ajax response they are redirecting to another URL.

The problem is that when I try to click on the above said link, it is not redirecting to any other URL and also not trapping any errors for click function. So I hope `click()` method executed successfully, but the page was not redirected to another URL. It is stopping me going further.

Any help or suggestions on this is appreciated.

HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="get_insert_update_click('http://www.samplewebsite.com/1250290CR','Showcase','1250290CR','CARS_PAGE','CAR_IN_FEATURED_CARS');" id="listing_image_290" name="listing_image_290" class="font_size_15"><img width="155" height="103" src="http://samplewebsite.com/public/uploads/processed/155x103-1409227190127_main_l.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Sample Script  to click on link:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("listing_image_290")));
try {
   driver.findElement(By.id("listing_image_290")).click();                                
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use try , catch to get error info? Also please share html and web driver code.

Comment: Hello Helping Hands ,  I have updated my question .Please check and  also I am not getting any errors even I am using try catch blocks also

Comment: Did ur scroll works properly ?

Answer (score 2):

I dont see "title_link_1013" in your HTML code, how should it find your `<a>` ? Maybe use the ID instead?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("listing_image_290")).click();
```

Comment: Sorry by mistake I have pasted wrong Id here, But I am trying with the correct iD

Comment: This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Understand there could be an issue with the browser preferences.
If the browser preferences / options are set to block the popup's then the re-directing link may not be working.

I will recommend to try with below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",<ChromeDriverPath>);

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);

prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", true);

chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

driver.findElement(By.id(<linkID>)).click
```