# Unable to click on html link using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I have an requirement of clicking on a link . I am using `click()` method to click on link by providing the locators and etc.., after click no action was taken place. When I see the html code anchor tag `href` attribute is having

```
"javascript:void(0)"
```

So there is no action taken place.The `id` of anchor tag is binded with java script and from there it is submitting the request.

How can I handle this scenario from selenium?

Comment: Are you sure the locator is correct and the click actually occurs?

Comment: yes I am 100% sure about the id and click functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my code, Anchor tag is having the href attribute as below

```
"javascript:void(0)
```

but when we click on anchor tag form was submitting though javascript. So in this case when `click()` to click on link will not work. we should use the `submit()`.

Finally this issue is resolved with following code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).submit();
```

Comment: This is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try triggering the Javascript event by using the Javascript native click:

```
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(...);
JavascriptExecutor exec = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
exec.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

Although I'm still convinced that a Selenium click will trigger Javascript code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`"javascript:void(0)"` means that the link wouldn't work. It'll do nothing. That is why no action is taking place when you click on it.

I have seen many developers do this when they don't want the link to "navigate" anywhere, though it's not the right practice.

You can read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean).

Comment: Hello @log_file,yes you are correct but when I manually clicking on the link,some action was taken place and redirected to another page.I am asking the same how we can do it using selenium

Comment: This shouldn't change for manual clicking and automated using Selenium. Is the JS function performing correctly?

Comment: Is it similar to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/click-method-is-not-working?rq=1. You asked this question

Comment: yes you are correct.Both are same issues but in different scenario's. I got the solution also.Any way Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after spending hours fighting with javascript:void(0)

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.website.com')
print (driver.title)

elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("something-here")
important_is_needed = elem.location_once_scrolled_into_view
elem.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

See this for Linux chrome install for selenium
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium

Note this comment "you can install chromium-chromdriver package (e.g. with apt-get) and add the path of the chromedriver file to the PATH shell variable PATH="${PATH}":/usr/lib/chromium-browser/ If you add this to your .bashrc, you won't need to set it each time you want to test with selenium" Thanks @Arpad Horvath

My install commands.

sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay

sudo apt-get install xvfb

sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

Also note the selenium ide firefox plugin can help.  Recording with the ide will tell you the correct string to use for find_element_by_css_selector.  Also, if this is new to you, firefox developer inspector tool and chrome inspect element tool are invaluable.